# How to retrieve a webpage with Go and convert it to UTF-8

Tags: go, utf-8

I need to download some big html files (about 300k+). Everything is working fine, the problem is that some of the files comes with Windows-1252/ISO-8859 characters like "á" or "ç" and when I save the document, Go converts it to characters like �. Any idea?

My code as follow:

```
package main

import (
  "io"
  "net/http"
  "os"
)

func main() {

  pagina := "http://www.mypage.com/doc?someparameters=123"
  err := DownloadFile("doc.html", pagina)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

}

func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) error {
  out, err := os.Create(filepath)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer out.Close()

  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  return nil
}
```

Comment: Use [`golang.org/x/text/encoding`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding). Usage examples can be found [there](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding?importers) as well.

Comment: Probably you will have to detect the encoding during downloading (e.g. by inspecting the Content-Type or peeking into the HTML for appropriate meta tags) and then apply @kostix's advice.

Comment: The Go program copies the response bytes to a file as is.  There is no conversion to characters like  � by the Go program. That's something that your terminal or editor are doing. The fix is to add a conversion as noted in previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
import "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"

rdrBody := charmap.Windows1252.NewDecoder().Reader(resp.Body)
_, err = io.Copy(out, rdrBody)

rdrBody := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(resp.Body)
_, err = io.Copy(out, rdrBody)
```

There are many other`ISO8859`encodings in package `charmap`.

---

A simple example of package `charmap.ISO8859_1` use:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    rdrBody := io.Reader(resp.Body)
    contentType := strings.ToLower(resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    if strings.Contains(contentType, "charset=iso-8859-1") {
        rdrBody = charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(rdrBody)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rdrBody)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    n := 256
    if n > len(body) {
        n = len(body)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body[:n]))
}
```